# Why are Anisakiasis infections relatively rare in Japan?

Tags: food, parasitology

In Japan raw fish are routinely eaten in the form of sushi and sashimi, and frequently no freezing or other preservative treatments have been applied. Even so, incidence of illness due to the common parasite Anisakiasis is reportedly only about 1000 cases per year. Given that very high concentrations of Anisakiasis and other nematodes are found in many types of food fishes, like mackerel, why would parasitical illness be so low?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a source for the "1000 cases per year" figure? In fact, a source I found states that [Japan accounts for 90% of global cases](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep43699), which would suggest that such infections are relatively *common* in Japan.

Comment: When a question includes the word *reportedly*, the question that follows is “reported by who?” It is expected that askers include sources for their claims, especially those as specific as a number of cases. Concerning your assertion that cases are relatively rare in Japan, *relatively* is the operative word, there. I took that to mean “relative to other countries”, hence my comment.

Comment: Regardless, the crux of your question is essentially “Why are cases in Japan lower than expected?” I believe the answer is “it isn’t”. What is the base rate of Anisakis-containing fish consumption in Japan and other countries? What is the *per-capita* incidence of Anisakiasis in Japan and other countries? What is the likelihood of Anisakiasis given parasite ingestion? Each of these questions needs to be answered before you can assert that Anisakiasis is “rare” in a given population.

Comment: What do you consider rare? Japan accounts for more than 90% cases of Anisakiasis globally. The rest 10% coming from other countries like Netherlands, Spain etc. So, you need to consider those countries.

Answer (score 0):

I read the freely available article:
“[Anisakidosis: perils of the deep](https://academic.oup.com/cid/article/51/7/806/354398)”.

It mentions that Japanese chefs are skilled at detecting Anisakis, hence infection is less likely.